# What does ': :' mean?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I wanted to log the ip of my node.js server to the console so I added:

```
console.log( server.address().address )
```

to my server code. I got this in return:

```
::
```

Does it mean that my server ip is not set? And if so, how can I set it?

EDIT 1; Here's the issue guys, when I compile my server file with Node, I get the following:
[image]

When I wanted to see how my app looks like in browser, I couldn't open it even though I tried all of these:

1. https://MyIPv4Address:443
2. 127.0.0.1:443
3. MyLink-LocalIPv6Address:443

Still I get nothing. That's why I asked you how can I possibly know which IP works.

Comment: What sort of object is `server`?

Comment: `::` is equivalent to the IPv6 address `0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0`.

Comment: @nwellnhof if this is the answer, why is it in comment form? please post as an answer.

Comment: @rlemon I didn't think my comment fully answered your question, so I didn't post it as answer.

Comment: @nwellnhof not my question :D but noted.

Comment: @nwellnhof: Sorry mate but the comments section is for seeking clarification, not for posting answers or half-answers. If you do not have a full answer, you can simply leave answering to someone who does.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit OK, so now I have ensure I have a full and correct answer?  I have to take on testing and verification for free, as well as looking at the gobs of dubious code often posted on SO?

Comment: @MartinJames: If you post an answer then you have a professional responsibility to do your best to ensure that it is factually accurate, yes.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The comment section is not only for clarification but also for [relevant but minor information to a post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). My comment clearly falls into the latter category.

Comment: @nwellnhof: Nope, you misinterpret that paragraph. It's clearly referring to meta-information (information _about the question_, not about the thing the question is asking about), not answers. It even helpfully gives examples!

Answer (score 8):

`::` is equivalent to the IPv6 address `0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0`

as pointed out by [@nwellnhof](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1956010/nwellnhof) in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30110874/what-does-mean#comment48332633_30110874)

You can read more about IPv6 [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6)

Answer (score 5):

`::` on its own is equivalent to the "unspecified" IPv6 address `0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0`.

In fact, any occurrence of `::` in an IPv6 address indicates a replacement with a string of 0-valued segments; ie. `fe80::101d` is shorthand for `fe80:0:0:0:0:0:0:101d`.